# How do I debug an Android app that crashes only in Release Mode

Tags: android, xamarin, entity-framework-core, android-8.1-oreo

Everything works in Debug Mode but Crashes in Release Mode. What required permissions are available in Debug Mode that are not turned on in Release mode?

**EDIT**

When I set Linking to None, I get past the first screen to my Login screen. However, when I added the Release permission `Internet`, the first time it tries to read a remote Entity Framework Core Table it crashes.

**EDIT 2**

In Release Mode, if I check `Use Shared Runtime`, the app runs fine.

**EDIT 3**

I have turned on Debugging while in Release mode Temporarily. The Following line throws a System.TypeInitializationException only in Release Mode:

```
if (_context.bma_users.Any(p => p.username == _name.Text) && _name.Text != string.Empty)
```

Comment: use appcenter.ms to enable crash reporting

Comment: Along with using AppCenter for reporting "remote" app crashes as Jason states, for "local" testing, review the logcat output of the device for crash details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=vswin

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding in release mode?

Comment: Yes, I tried that every change @MohammadOmidvar. Thanks for you input.

Comment: As you say this is not happening when `Use Shared Runtime` is checked, it can be the linking.
Simply go to project properties and set linking to `None`. Your apk size may grow very much, but if problem is solved, you can find the problematic library and just skip linking that one.

Comment: Linking is set to None @MohammadOmidvar.

Comment: Why dont you use Fabric's Crashlytics?? You wont need to plug the phone every time there is an crash.

Comment: It seems you have a library that works only on debug mode. Did you check library list for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to set `Additional supported encodings` to `West` in the `Android Options` screen under `Project Properties`. It doesn't seem related but I was trying every possible combination and this finally worked.

Comment: Honestly, what you're on?

Answer (score 12):

**IF YOU JUST WANT TO SEE THE CRASH LOG:**

Assuming you have Android Studio and no crash report service implemented ([Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android), [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/), etc...)

You might want to **see the crash log print** first:

- Open the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running) in Android Studio.
- Change `Log Level` to `Error`.
- Make sure [USB debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#debugging) is enabled on your device.
- Connect your device to the computer.
- Make the app crash and see what it prints.

If you **can't reproduce**:

Next time it crashes, connect the device and do the same as above. Usually the log history will be available to view, scroll until you find the crash :)

Look for `FATAL EXCEPTION`

- Keep in mind - using the Logcat search bar can clear the log history, in most cases you can reconnect your device to view it again.

Comment: While you will probably find the reason for the crash, this is not an answer on how to **debug** in release mode.

Answer (score 5):

You already assume "permission", not sure why...

The first thing I disable when I have something crashing only in release mode is minify (aka ProGuard). So disable the obfuscation, build again and try to see if you still get crashes. If not, reenable proguard one line at a time to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: ProGuard is not enabled

Answer (score 1):

You can just set `debuggable: true` for your `release` build type. 
Don't forget to remove this property once you're done with debugging.

Comment: I have same prob as OP, when I do put debuggable: true, it no longer crashes, but I can't release that to the play store...!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of the android section and then into the Android options tab.

Make sure that the "Use Shared Runtime" and "Use Fast Deployment" boxes are unticked in your release configuration

[image: Properties page]

Answer (score -1):

You can use any of the **crashlytics tools** like Firebase Analytics, Fabric, Splunk Mint to get the exact crash log