# React Native App crashing in release mode only after a successful build

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My project is working fine in debug mode but in release mode it is crashing right after the splash screen on Android I have not built it on ios yet.
It was crashing in react-native version 0.57.0 and now I have downgraded it to version 0.55.4 which is working alright in one of my other projects

**I have already tried**

- deleting and re installing node modules.
- re ejecting my project
- cd android and run gradlew, gradlew clean

**This is my package.json file**

```
{   "name": "projectName",   
    "version": "1.0.1",   
    "private": true,   
    "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/Fonts/Fonts"
    ]   
   },   
   "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"   
     },   
    "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-countdown-circle": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-percentage-circle": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-sliding-panes": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-toast": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0",
    "react-swipeable-views-native": "^0.12.9"   
    },   
    "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "jest": "23.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"   
    },   
    "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"   
     }
```

}

**This is my Android/build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

**This is my Android/App/build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "projName"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-toast')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**This is what I got by running adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V**

> -------- beginning of system
>   --------- beginning of main 10-24 12:43:04.376  3411  3411 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor() 10-24 12:43:04.466  3411 
>   3411 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground() 10-24
>   12:43:04.466  3411  3411 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner() 10-24
>   12:44:52.606  3411  3411 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer() 10-24 12:44:52.606 
>   3411  3411 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground() 10-24
>   12:44:52.606  3411  3411 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread() 10-24
>   12:44:52.692  3411  3473 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext() 10-24 12:44:53.020  3411 
>   3473 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge. 10-24
>   12:44:53.025  3411  3473 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat
>   Bridge before initializeBridge 10-24 12:44:53.066  3411  3473 D
>   ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
>   10-24 12:44:53.067  3411  3473 D ReactNative:
>   CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle() 10-24 12:44:53.067  3411  3477 D
>   ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext() 10-24
>   12:44:53.068  3411  3477 D ReactNative:
>   CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize() 10-24 12:44:53.070  3411  3477 D
>   ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance() 10-24
>   12:44:54.244  3411  3476 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "goHard"
>   with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. **DEV** === true, development-level
>   warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF 10-24 12:44:54.981 
>   3411  3476 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in
>   plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to clean up
>   subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent
>   memory leaks. 10-24 12:45:39.086  3411  3476 I ReactNativeJS: 1 10-24
>   12:45:47.124  3411  3476 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: isMounted(...) is
>   deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to
>   clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to
>   prevent memory leaks. 10-24 12:45:54.050  3411  3476 I ReactNativeJS:
>   loading started 10-24 12:46:05.064  3411  3476 W ReactNativeJS:
>   Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React
>   classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending
>   requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks. 10-24
>   12:46:05.252  3411  3476 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: isMounted(...) is
>   deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to
>   clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to
>   prevent memory leaks. 10-24 12:46:26.850  3411  3476 W ReactNativeJS:
>   Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React
>   classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending
>   requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks. 10-24
>   12:46:31.782  3411  3476 I ReactNativeJS: loading started 10-24
>   12:46:39.773  3411  3476 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: isMounted(...) is
>   deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to
>   clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to
>   prevent memory leaks. 10-24 12:53:39.697  3411  3476 W ReactNativeJS:
>   Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React
>   classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending
>   requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks. 10-24
>   12:55:59.792  3870  3870 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
>   10-24 12:55:59.805  3870  3870 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground() 10-24
>   12:55:59.805  3870  3870 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner() 10-24
>   12:55:59.805  3870  3870 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
>   10-24 12:55:59.805  3870  3870 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground() 10-24
>   12:55:59.805  3870  3870 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread() 10-24
>   12:55:59.855  3870  3885 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext() 10-24 12:56:00.192  3870 
>   3885 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge. 10-24
>   12:56:00.198  3870  3885 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat
>   Bridge before initializeBridge 10-24 12:56:00.217  3870  3885 D
>   ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
>   10-24 12:56:00.218  3870  3885 D ReactNative:
>   CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
>   --------- beginning of crash 10-24 13:20:48.743  4074  4074 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor() 10-24 13:20:48.754  4074 
>   4074 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground() 10-24
>   13:20:48.754  4074  4074 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner() 10-24
>   13:20:48.754  4074  4074 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
>   10-24 13:20:48.754  4074  4074 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground() 10-24
>   13:20:48.754  4074  4074 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread() 10-24
>   13:20:48.792  4074  4089 D ReactNative:
>   ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext() 10-24 13:20:49.048  4074 
>   4089 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge. 10-24
>   13:20:49.052  4074  4089 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat
>   Bridge before initializeBridge 10-24 13:20:49.095  4074  4089 D
>   ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
>   10-24 13:20:49.096  4074  4089 D ReactNative:
>   CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()

Comment: Logcat will tell you the problem. Please attach logcat and community will try to help you.

Comment: You can view the crash log of the release version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51843980/4255978

Comment: I have posted the crash logs